# What are the advantages of interfaces and abstract classes?

Tags: php, oop, interface, abstract-class

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [purpose of interface in classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601034/purpose-of-interface-in-classes)
>   [What is the difference between an interface and abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913098/what-is-the-difference-between-an-interface-and-abstract-class)

Hi I am a php programmer. any body can explain what is the advantage of using interface and abstract class.

Comment: Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php

Comment: A possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913098/php-what-is-the-difference-between-an-interface-and-abstract-class

Comment: ... or any other of the millions of resources on it (note that language-agnostic resources should mostly apply here, too, so you can avoid the sometimes scaringly low-quality PHP examples).

Comment: You should begin to read all of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=abstract+interface

Comment: See also [What is the point of interfaces in a weakly-typed language like PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758254/what-is-the-point-of-interfaces-in-a-weakly-typed-language-like-php)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The main advantage of an interface is that it allows you to define a protocol to be implemented for an object to have some behavior. For example, you could have a Comparable interface with a compare method for classes to implement, and every class that implements it would have a standardized method for comparison.

Abstract classes allow you to define a common base for several concrete classes. For example, let's say you wanted to define classes representing animals:

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract protected function eat();
    abstract protected function sleep();
    public function die() {
        // Do something to indicate dying
    }
}
```

In this case, we define `eat()` and `sleep()` as abstract because different types of animals (e.g. lion, bear, etc.) that will inherit from `Animal` eat and sleep in different ways. But all animals die the same way (don't hold me to that), so we can define a common function for that. Using an abstract class helped us 1.) declare some common methods that all `Animal`s should have, and 2.) define common behavior for `Animal`s. So, when you extend `Animal`, you won't have to rewrite the code for `die()`.