# when to use abstract class and when to use interface in c#

Tags: c#, oop

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [interface and abstract class.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607081/interface-and-abstract-class)
>   [Abstract classes vs Interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474249/abstract-classes-vs-interfaces)

Can anyone tell me when one should use an abstract class and when one should use an interface with sample scenarios?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474249/abstract-classes-vs-interfaces

Comment: Lots of duplicates here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987253/interface-vs-abstract-class for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're defining *behavior* (like `IEnumerable`, since a `List` acts like an `IEnumerable`), then use an interface, but if you're defining a *kind* of object (an IS-A) relationship, use an abstract class (like `Stream` -- since a `MemoryStream` IS-A `Stream`).

Answer (score 3):

You should use an abstract class if you need to supply a base implementation.

Otherwise, use an interface.

Comment: anyway, this is a straightforward great answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to provide an implementation of a method/set of methods but don't want people to directly instantiate your parent class, use an Abstract Class.

If you want to define what members a class must interface, but not provide any implementation, use an Interface.